# Laravel 6 - Ajax - retreiving file - Internal error 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to fetch file via ajax from the laravel storage (I don't want to use the public folder as the docs should be only available for the admins). So the Ajax function calls a Route (post) , which calls the controller function to respond, but getting 500 internal server error in the console all the time.
If I dd() the request, or some string right in the begining of the controller function I get that back as output. so the request actually happens with the proper data. CSRF tokens are included.
The route:

```
    Route::post('/tes/admin/filter/docview/', 'AdminTravelExpenseController@showdoc')- 
    >name('admin.tes.displayDoc');
```

The controller:

```
         public function __construct()
        {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        //adminvalidator here

        }

         public function showdoc(Request $request){
           $item = \App\TravelExpense::find($request['id']);

           if($request['src'] == 1){
            $url = $item->doc_url1 ;
          }
          else{
            $url = $item->doc_url2 ;
          }

           if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists($filePath)){
            abort(404);
           }
           $file = File::get($path);
           $type = File::mimeType($path);
           $response = Response::make($file, 200);
           $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

           return \Response::json($response);
          }
```

And the ajax:

```
      $('.docview').on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var src = $(this).data('src');
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('id', id);
        form_data.append('src', src);
        $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });
        $.ajax({
          url: '/tes/admin/filter/docview/',
          type: "POST",
            processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          data: form_data,
          success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            $('.docDisplay').html(data);

          }
        });
       });
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help with debugging until you provide the actual error. Whenever a 500 error happens, it's logged internally to Laravel's logs, found in `storage/logs/laravel.log` (by default). See if you can include the actual error.

Comment: That being said, at a glance, there's an issue with `->exists($filePath)){`; I don't see where you're defining `$filePath`. Same with `$path` a little further down: `File::get($path);` and `File::mimeType($path);`

Comment: Thanks for the help, the logs helped to fix it, (missed to add some of the used Facades)

Comment: Ah yes, that would be an issue too if you're missing some `use ...` declarations. But yeah, everything is logged to that internal file (unless it's a more severe error, at which point its logged to your server log). For AJAX requests, you _should_ be able to see the error when it happens via your browser's developer tools, as long as you have `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file. The `Network` tab will show requests and responses, including the detailed 500 error should it happen.